# Unwanted padding or gaps in html list of linked images

Tags: html, css, border, margin, padding

I am trying to make list of images act as a horizontal navigation bar. Unfortunately try as I might I cannot get the images to sit next to each other. I have tried eliminating padding, margin and border from each of the nested image, link, list item and unordered list.

The html code is simple

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Menu App</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-1">content</div>
    <div id="footer">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/zone.png" alt="toggle zones"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/nr.png" alt="toggle nr services"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/wheel.png" alt="toggle wheelchair access"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cycle.png" alt="toggle cycle access"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css code is as follows

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
}

li a {
    display: block;
}

li a img {
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

**Extra Details**

The natural size of the images is 40px by 40px
When checking in chrome

- the size of the image is 40px by 40px
- the size of the a tag is 40px by 45px ???
- the size of the li tag is back to 40px by 40px
- the height of the ul and div#footer are both 45??
- there is white space between the grey backgrounds of the buttons

So to summarise I would like to remove the white space and reduce the height of the whole list to the height of the buttons (without forcing it to 40 px) so it still works in my fluid layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're treating the `<li>` elements as `inline-block`s.  These essentially act and flow as text characters, and if there is white-space between them in the HTML, then white-space will appear next to them on the page as well.  You can either set `font-size` to be `0` within the `<ul>`, or use `display: block` and `float: left` instead to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: That doesn't remove the bottom space. Vertical-align:top should also be used on the `<li>`elements and the `<img>`elements.

Comment: It removed the bottom space for me.

Comment: Also problem with the float method is that I have to then reconsider centring the whole lot

Comment: Yes, using the float method would require some rethought there, you could potentially centre align the `<ul>` as an `inline-block` and float the `<li>`s within that.  Using floating blocks is the less hacky option, but `font-size: 0` should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Add
`vertical-align: top`
to your 
`li a img` and your `li`
in order to get rid of that 5px bottom space

To get rid of the horizontal space,  set the font-size of `<ul>` to 0

Comment: @PeterSaxton Mix my solution with LukeGT's solution

Comment: @PeterSaxton I mixed the two solutions in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `display:inline-block` will cause the browser to display whitespace characters around the `<li>` elements. In order to remove this extra whitespace, you have to do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/zone.png" alt="toggle zones"></a></li
    ><li><a href="#"><img src="img/nr.png" alt="toggle nr services"></a></li
    ><li><a href="#"><img src="img/wheel.png" alt="toggle wheelchair access"></a></li
    ><li><a href="#"><img src="img/cycle.png" alt="toggle cycle access"></a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I'm removing the extra space between the tags.

For more information, see: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Useful link, they all seam like annoying fixes but if they work

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `font-size` of  `<ul>` to `0` in your CSS

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lahmf/CLcfq/1/)